# Using a single speaker to play e.g. Youtube audio

Tags: audio, speakers, mono

I thought I'd save money/space by using a single monitor - in most music players I can "downmix to mono" and then shift the balance to full left or right

However I cannot downmix Youtube videos and therefore they are currently silent. I cannot use Playback Devices > Levels > Balance because that would just silence one side of the stereo without mixing (it's not a "pan").

Does anyone understand why feeding balanced stereo into one speaker results in silence, too? It happens when playing on musicbee as well if I centre the balance

Comment: Phase issues. Left & Right are phase-inverted to each other, resulting in total cancellation when summed.[which also, incidentally, means the original signal is mono, other than the inversion] Easiest to do when plugging in 'bare wire' speakers, but possible in other areas too.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I'm just using an audio jack so it has two connectors, I guess these are just positive and negative

Comment: my main software issue still remains btw

Comment: Also, it depends how the YouTube video was created. Was the video created in 5.1, Stereo, Mono, etc. Try doing the same test with this video which was done in 5.1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qJylrvcBn0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a mono cable? I remember myself using a single earphone plugged into a walkman (yes - a blast from the past) and you should get a physical downmix. Another thing that I have experienced was connecting a samsung stereo headset to a nokia phone which had a different depth of the audio jack and the sound was terrible unless I pulled the plug a bit out so it sent the sound on both channels. A third thing, when I plug something onto the audio jack on my laptop I get a pop up asking me what I have connected (headphones, headset, speaker out,..) so it sure will change the way how the sound will be sent to the jack.

Hopefully I did not misunderstood your problem :)

Comment: I can order a mono cable but this "physical downmix" should have the phase issues @Tetsujin mentioned right?

Comment: Not sure. As told - it was a long time ago I experienced it. Maybe @Tetsujin could comment on this. Probably depends on the output. I just now saw that there definitely some magic is going on. I have plugged in a X-mini speaker, told the pop up it is a headset and plugged my samsung earphones with mic into the x-mini - and I can use it in windows. So there is some phase shifting it seems, because the x-mini has a 3 way (ground,left,right) and the earphone/mic has a 4 way (ground,left,right,mic) and it is working. You could measure the output with a multimeter before buying - just to make sure.